# Random white screen in 16.10

Tags: 16.10

I am dual booting Ubuntu 16.10 with Windows 7. Tried to reinstall Grub2 with Bootrepair, still getting random white screen.

CPU: AMD X2 250
RAM: 4GB
GPU: Built-in 760G

Comment: It is not related to grub.

Comment: I saw a guide here say if you have dual boot, maybe reinstalling Grub will fix this error